# Checking if picturebox is empty gives "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." exception

Tags: c#, arrays, exception, null, picturebox

I have problem with setting an image to PictureBox if its empty... I tried few different ways of doing it and I always get same exception. By reading articles here and on the web this should work but it doesn't...

I have declared 6 arrays of PBs...

```
    PictureBox[] red1 = new PictureBox[4];
    PictureBox[] red2 = new PictureBox[4];
    PictureBox[] red3 = new PictureBox[4];
    PictureBox[] red4 = new PictureBox[4];
    PictureBox[] red5 = new PictureBox[4];
    PictureBox[] red6 = new PictureBox[4];
```

On FormLoad event those arrays are populated with appropriet PBs...

```
     PictureBox[] red1 = { pok11, pok12, pok13, pok14 };
     PictureBox[] red2 = { pok21, pok22, pok23, pok24 };
     PictureBox[] red3 = { pok31, pok32, pok33, pok34 };
     PictureBox[] red4 = { pok41, pok42, pok43, pok44 };
     PictureBox[] red5 = { pok51, pok52, pok53, pok54 };
     PictureBox[] red6 = { pok61, pok62, pok63, pok64 };
```

And when I call method to use them the exception is thrown...

Call:

```
     DodajSLIKU(Properties.Resources.HERCv2, red1);
```

Method:

```
    public void DodajSLIKU(Image slika, PictureBox[] t)
    {            
        if (t[0].Image == null)   //where exception occures.
            t[0].Image = slika;
        else if (t[1].Image == null)
            t[1].Image = slika;
        else if (t[2].Image == null)
            t[2].Image = slika;
        else if (t[3].Image == null)
            t[3].Image = slika;
        else
            return;
    }
```

Where am I doing it wrong? Thanks...

Comment: Which variable/property is null (not set to an instance of an object)?

Comment: Where did the exception occur? A stacktrace would be great!

Comment: I edited question to show where ex is occuring. And I am checking if Image propery is null, if you are asking me that...

Comment: Its possible that `t[0]` is empty in which case you'd get the NRE.  When it happens hold your mouse over `t` to see.

Comment: It shouldn't be empty cuz I am calling the method after form is loaded and PictureBox pok11 is add to it...

Comment: `pok11, pok12, pok13, pok14` probably are null. Use the __DEBUGGER__!

Comment: Yes, that was the problem... Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Change your method signature like the following:

```
public void DodajSLIKU(Image slika, PictureBox[] t)
        {
            foreach (var item in t)
            {
                if (item != null)
                {
                    if (item.Image == null)  
                        item.Image = slika;
                }
            }            
        }
```

Comment: Using this I don't get Exception any more, but the problem is that item IS null so nothing happens. Is my declaration wrong? I cannot figure  that one out...